# How to print the results of depth wise convolution in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am applying depth wise convolution. I want to access the first part of the 4 by 4 image and 2 by 2 filter between which convolution is taking place. Can someone please tell me how I can do that?

```
 `input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,4,4,2]))
 filter= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2,2,1]))
 def depth_conv2d(input):
     return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(input,filter, strides=[1,2,2,1],padding= 'SAME')
 depth_conv_out = depth_conv2d(input)
 sess = tf. InteractiveSession()
 sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
 print input.eval()[0][:3][:3]`
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

you want the 4x4 of the first "color" of the image, and the 2x2 that will filter that first "color"

## Solution

```
import tensorflow as tf

input  = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,4,4,2]))
filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2,2,1]))
def depth_conv2d(input):
     return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(input,filter, strides=[1,2,2,1],padding= 'SAME')
depth_conv_out = depth_conv2d(input)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

print "The first part of the 4x4 image"
input_data = sess.run(input)
print input_data[:,:,:,0]
print "The first part of the 2x2 filter"
filter_data = sess.run(filter)
print filter_data[:,:,0,0]
```

## Result

```
The first part of the 4x4 image
[[[ 0.17095199 -0.24415942 -0.15299758  0.00659828]
  [ 1.87758398  0.88201404  0.22255163 -0.52048266]
  [-0.20067528  0.98255271 -2.09791732 -0.43816876]
  [-0.37301171  0.6178537   2.05873895  1.97340238]]]
The 2x2 filter
[[-0.48764563  1.009269  ]
 [-0.82577544  0.75439191]]
```